# Data extensions Different Syntax for First Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 3 data extensions and in 2 of them the syntax of First Name is the same and in the third the syntax is different. I am trying to write a script to pull the First name. The amp script is working; the only issue I am facing is when the same email address with the same key is in 2 data extensions; although its deduped at the time of the send the first name appears twice. I can't figure what exactly is missing in the if logic to prevent this. 
I know I can use a query activity to format the name for the third DE to match the other 2 and use the %%%% for pulling the first name but I need to understand why my current script isnt working.

Any idea is appreciated! thanks, G

```
%%[ 

var @rows2,@row2,@rowCount2
Var @lookupValue2
SET @lookupValue2=AttributeValue('Contact ID')
SET @rows2=LookupRows('FirstNamesDEs','Contact ID',@lookupValue2)
SET @rowCount2=rowcount(@rows2)

If @rowCount2>0 then 
    Var @first2
    SET @row2=row(@rows2,1)
    SET @first2=field(@row2,'First Name')
]%%
%%[else]%%
%%[endif]%%

%%[ 

var @rows3,@row3,@rowCount3
Var @lookupValue3
SET @lookupValue3=AttributeValue('Contact ID')
SET @rows3=LookupRows('FirstNamesDe2','Contact ID',@lookupValue3)
SET @rowCount3=rowcount(@rows3)

If @rowCount3>0 then 
    Var @first3
    SET @row3=row(@rows3,1)
    SET @first3=field(@row3,'First_Name')
]%%
%%[else]%% 
%%[endif]%%

%%[ 
var @rows4,@row4,@rowCount4 
Var @lookupValue4
SET @lookupValue4=AttributeValue('Contact ID')
SET @rows4=LookupRows('FirstNames_Exclusions','Contact ID',@lookupValue4)

SET @rowCount4=rowcount(@rows4)

If @rowCount4>0 then 
    Var @first4
    SET @row4=row(@rows4,1)
    SET @first4=field(@row4,'First_Name')
]%%
%%[else]%%
%%[endif]%%

%%[if @first2==@first3==@first4 then]%%
    %%=v(@first2)=%%
%%[endif]%%
%%[else]%%

%%[if @first2==@first3 then]%%
    %%=v(@first2)=%%
%%[else]%%
%%[endif]%%

%%[if @first2==@first4 then]%%
    %%=v(@first2)=%%
%%[else]%%
%%[endif]%%

%%[if @first3==@first4 then]%%
    %%=v(@first3)=%%
%%[else]%%
%%[endif]%%

%%[if not empty (@first2) OR not empty (@first3) or not empty (@first4) then]%%
    %%=v(@first2)=%%%%=v(@first3)=%%%%=v(@first4)=%%
%%[else]%%

    %%[
    var @text 
    set @text="Dear Traveler" 
    Output(v(@text))
    ]%%

%%[endif]%%
```

Comment: sorry for the terrible formatting. In my notepad the format showed the code correctly formatted

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish what you're wanting in a much simpler way -- by utilizing the [**Lookup()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) and [**empty()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm) functions:

```
%%[

var @contactID, @first2, @first3, @first4, @firstName
set @contactID = AttributeValue('Contact ID')
var @first2 = Lookup("FirstNamesDEs", "First Name", "Contact ID", @contactID)
var @first3 = Lookup("FirstNamesDe2", "First_Name", "Contact ID", @contactID)
var @first4 = Lookup("FirstNames_Exclusions", "First_Name", "Contact ID", @contactID)

/* for debugging */
output(concat("<br>contactID: ", @contactID))
output(concat("<br>first2: ", @first2))
output(concat("<br>first3: ", @first3))
output(concat("<br>first4: ", @first4))

if not empty(@first2) then

  set @firstName = @first2

elseif not empty(@first3) then

  set @firstName = @first3

elseif not empty(@first4) then

  set @firstName = @first4

else

 set @firstName = "Traveler"

endif

output(concat("<br>Dear ", properCase(@firstName), ","))

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! I am very new to amp script. Very elegant solution. Didn't know I can just declare the AttributeValue one time if the syntax for this field is the same in my data extensions. Makes total sense and it achieves what I need.